# Regexp to strip away wrapping DIV-tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, strip

In certain cases the response from the server is wrapped in a DIV-tag like this:

```html
<div id="marker-aab44ba9d64a41398ed97a251dfb938e-629">42</div>
```

The content of the tag might be whatever: A string, a number, a URL, a javascript array, a javascript object.

The format of the tag is always:

```html
<div id="marker-[random string here]">content</div>
```

I'd like to use a regular expression to strip away the tag, how can I do this?

And remember: The response from the server might be just the content without the wrapping DIV, so the regexp should account for that.

Comment: it doesn't sound complicated, have you tried something yourself?

Comment: Don't use regexp. Use DOM methods. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/v8S7Z/ . It depends on what you actually need and what can exactly be in the response

Comment: @ Lan, great answer. Please put answers in the answers field and not the comments.

Comment: Can your content between divs be html?

Comment: @Denomales Thanks. I like to suggest it in the comments first, when I'm not 100% sure what's needed. If I get good feedback, then I post an answer...which I just did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
function (string) {
    var match = string.match('<div id="marker-[^"]*">(.*)</div>');
    if(match) {
        return $(string).html(); 
    } else {
        return string; 
    }
};
```

:-)

Answer (score 5):

You could use anchors:

```
var res = str.replace(/^<div[^>]*>|<\/div>$/g, '');
```

If your content between `div` tags is in HTML, you can use this to be sure to remove only the divs you want:

```
var res = str.replace(/^<div[^>]*? id\s*=\s*["']?marker-[^>]+>([\S\s]*)<\/div>$/g, '\1');
```

Comment: This affects all the divs.

Comment: @HamZa Yeah, but `str` is pretty local in this case.

Comment: @HamZa:no, it doesn't, because it's anchored.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Well I was surprised that you didn't take in account `id="marker-..."`, I know you could do it easily :)

Comment: @HamZa: I'm not sure it's needed, since the OP doesn't specify that the content may be html.